# Why does my heading not change using Core Location?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-location

I'm using a WiFi iPad 1st gen with iOS 5.1.1

I have set up Core Location similar to this blog post:
http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2012/01/10/how-to-create-a-compass-in-iphone/

In:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading*)heading
```

I log the true heading value:

```
NSLog(@"heading: %f", manager.heading.trueHeading);
```

The result is always "true heading: -1.000000" no matter which direction I point the iPad.

I've rotated the device on all 3 axis and enabled location services in settings.

Any ideas on why this doesn't work?  Does heading reporting not work on an iPad 1st gen?

Comment: Does 'YES == manager.headingAvailable' ?

Comment: NSLog(@"Heading avail: %@", (manager.headingAvailable ? @"Yes" : @"No") == YES

Comment: The answer is YES? (your above code is missing a paren.)

Comment: Yes, the heading is available, and it sends updates every time I move the device, but the heading is always the same

Answer (score 3):

Here is what helped in my case :

1. Select Location Services (under privacy settings)
2. Select System Services at the bottom of the list of apps (in the Location Services)
3. Turn your **Compass Calibration ON**

It seems that this way, the trueheading-values no longer turn out to be -1 !

(see picture below) !

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I can't mark correct as this was an old project and I'm not working on it anymore.  I did up vote, and hopefully if someone else runs into this issue it will help them.

Answer (score 2):

To get valid heading data you must also configure the CLLocationManager to update location as well.  From the Apple documentation:

> Note: If you want heading objects to contain valid data for the
>   trueHeading property, your location manager object should also be
>   configured to deliver location updates. You can start the delivery of
>   these updates by calling the location manager object’s
>   startUpdatingLocation method.

Thus call `startUpdatingLocation`

Note that 'heading' refers to the direction that a defined device axis is pointed.  The 'orientation', which you can read with [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation tells you the tilt of the device.

Comment: This is so strange.  I set the app up with the kCLLocationAccuracyBest, headingFilter of 1, set the delegate, called startUpdatingLocation and startUpdatingHeading.  I still get -1.000000 each time I move the device, even after rotating around all 3 axis several times.  However, I am able to get magnetic heading.

Answer (score 1):

The -1 means the compass heading is invalid. You probably need to perform compass calibration.

Comment: I rotated the device around all 3 axis several times, and yet no change.

Comment: You should look at heading.trueHeading, not manager.heading.trueHeading

Comment: Changed, but still gets a -1.000000 result  :(